# What does this not like about my AddPartner procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, database-design

So I'm getting a slew of errors

> (1 row(s) affected) Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Line 48 Could not
>   find stored procedure 'AddPartner'. Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Line
>   49 Could not find stored procedure 'AddPartner'. Msg 2812, Level 16,
>   State 62, Line 50 Could not find stored procedure 'AddPartner'.
>
> (1 row(s) affected)
>
> (1 row(s) affected) Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Procedure AddAnswer,
>   Line 114 The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY
>   constraint "FK__Answers__partner__145C0A3F". The conflict occurred in
>   database "SurveyDb", table "dbo.Partners", column 'id'. The statement
>   has been terminated. Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Procedure AddAnswer,
>   Line 114 The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY
>   constraint "FK__Answers__partner__145C0A3F". The conflict occurred in
>   database "SurveyDb", table "dbo.Partners", column 'id'. The statement
>   has been terminated. Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Procedure AddAnswer,
>   Line 114 The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY
>   constraint "FK__Answers__partner__145C0A3F". The conflict occurred in
>   database "SurveyDb", table "dbo.Partners", column 'id'. The statement
>   has been terminated. Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Procedure AddAnswer,
>   Line 114 The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY
>   constraint "FK__Answers__partner__145C0A3F". The conflict occurred in
>   database "SurveyDb", table "dbo.Partners", column 'id'. The statement
>   has been terminated.

and I think they all originate from the first 3 errors about `AddPartner`, however I cannot figure out the exact source of the problem as I've looked over my syntax plenty of times. On a related note, does there exist some sort of online tool that can help one get hints for debugging SQL errors?

```
-- Create database for all information 
-- needed in the application, set as context
CREATE DATABASE SurveyDb;
GO
USE SurveyDb;
-- Create surveys table
GO
CREATE TABLE Surveys (
    id INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    title NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
GO
-- Create sprocs for adding and deleting surveys
CREATE PROCEDURE AddSurvey
    @title NVARCHAR(100)
AS
    INSERT INTO Surveys (title) VALUES (@title)
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE DeleteSurvey
    @id INT
AS
    DELETE FROM Surveys WHERE id=@id
GO
-- Seed the surveys table with 1 sample survey
EXEC AddSurvey @title = "Survey Numero Uno";

GO
-- Create partners table 
CREATE TABLE Partners ( 
    id INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    name NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
GO
-- Create sprocs for adding and deleting partners
CREATE PROCEDURE AddParter
    @name NVARCHAR(50) 
AS
    INSERT INTO Partners (name) VALUES (@name)
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE DeletePartner
    @id INT
AS
    DELETE FROM Partners WHERE id=@id
GO
-- Seed the partners table with a few samples
EXEC AddPartner @name = 'Haliburton';
EXEC AddPartner @name = 'Berkshite Hathaway';
EXEC AddPartner @name = 'Infosys';

GO
-- Create questions table. Questions are associated with
-- a particular survey. If the survey is deleted then so
-- are all associated questions.
CREATE TABLE Questions (
    id INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    survey_id INT,
    qtext NVARCHAR(300) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (survey_id) REFERENCES Surveys(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
GO
-- Create sprocs for adding and deleting questions. 
CREATE PROCEDURE AddQuestion
    @survey_id INT, 
    @qtext NVARCHAR(300)
AS
    INSERT INTO Questions (survey_id, qtext) VALUES (@survey_id, @qtext)
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE DeleteQuestion
    @id INT
AS
    DELETE FROM Questions WHERE id=@id
GO
-- Seed the questions table with sample questions.
EXEC AddQuestion @survey_id = 1, @qtext = 'What is the average velocity of an African swallow?';
EXEC AddQuestion @survey_id = 1, @qtext = 'How hot is she, on a scale of 1.0-100.0?';

GO
-- Create table for answers. Answers are associated with both
-- a question and a partner. If either the question or partner
-- is deleted then so are all associated answers.
CREATE TABLE Answers ( 
    id INT IDENTITY (1,1),
    question_id INT,
    partner_id INT,
    val DECIMAL NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (question_id) REFERENCES Questions(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (partner_id) REFERENCES Partners(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

GO
-- Create sprocs for adding and deleting answers. 
CREATE PROCEDURE AddAnswer
    @question_id INT,   
    @partner_id INT,
    @val DECIMAL
AS
    INSERT INTO Answers (question_id, partner_id, val) VALUES (@question_id, @partner_id, @val)
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE DeleteAnswer
    @id INT
AS
    DELETE FROM Answers WHERE id=@id
GO
-- Seed the questions table with sample answers.
EXEC AddAnswer @question_id = 1, @partner_id = 1, @val = 23.3;
EXEC AddAnswer @question_id = 2, @partner_id = 1, @val = 99.5;
EXEC AddAnswer @question_id = 1, @partner_id = 2, @val = 0.12345;
EXEC AddAnswer @question_id = 2, @partner_id = 2, @val = 0.19;
```

Comment: your procedure name is `AddParter`  not  `AddPartner`

Comment: i dont see the creation of a procedure named AddPartner. that probably also caused the foreign key violations

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the `AddAnswer` procedure.  You're adding partner id's that don't exist in the partner table, so referential integrity fails.  Look in your partner table ( `select * from partners` ) and see what the id's are.

Other than that, I'd say that 1) you need to add some checking before inserting rows.  If you try to add 'Berkshire Hathaway' twice, it's going to error.  Check first and you don't have that problem:

```
if not exists ( select * from partners where [name] = @name )
    begin
        INSERT INTO Partners (name) VALUES (@name)
    end
```

Also: you should really consider not using a column named `name` - call it PartnerName or something, sure, but having random `name` columns doesn't help readability and may cause syntax-checking problems down the road.

**EDIT**: Or, as Jamie points out, correct the typo in the stored procedure name.

Comment: the only problem with the query is that he named his `AddPartner` procedure `AddParter`.. just a simple spelling error

Comment: Ahh.  So, because of the typo, the records don't get added & the subsequent calls fail due to FK violation.  Well spotted.